# Rails 5 - I need to return the first record of a group, but there are records that have no group

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

So as the title suggests I need to return the records from a table, where these records can belong to a group.
If there are several records in a group, return only the last one, and if the record does not belong to any group, return it together.

I have the following tables

> (automation_execution) 1 --> n (automation_execution_action) 1 <---> 1 (workable)

I need to return workable table records, where they may or may not be linked to automation tables.

**automation_execution**

| id | company_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

**automation_execution_ations**

| id | automation_execution_id | workable_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

**workable**

| id | company_id | status | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | finished | 2022-01-19 19:48:24 |
| 2 | 1 | processing | 2022-01-19 18:00:24 |
| 3 | 1 | processing | 2022-01-19 18:00:24 |
| 4 | 1 | processing | 2022-01-19 18:00:24 |

In the example above, we have 4 workables, 1 and 2 belong to an automation and 3 and 4 do not, in this example I would need to return the record 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this SQL works:

```sql
select workables.*
from (
         select workables.*,
                automation_execution_actions.automation_execution_id,
                row_number()
                over (partition by automation_execution_actions.automation_execution_id order by workables.id desc) as rn
         from workables
                  left join automation_execution_actions on automation_execution_actions.workable_id = workables.id
     ) as workables
where rn = 1
   OR automation_execution_id IS NULL
order by id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I did not know this SQL OVER function, I researched it to better understand and found it very interesting, I will apply it and other queries I have.

Comment: You're welcome. It's very usefull if you want to do aggregates without actual grouping.

Comment: A lateral join would be a more performant option.